# Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I tried the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE test(x IN account.Accno%TYPE,y IN 
account.Balance%TYPE)
IS
    cur_balance account.Balance%TYPE(20);
BEGIN
    select Balance
    into cur_balance
    from Account
    where Accno = x;
    if cur_balance < y then
        dbms_output.put_line('The amount entered is more than the amount balance');
    else
        update Account
        set Balance =cur_balance-y
    where Accno = x;
    end if; 
    dbms_output.put_line('Money has been withdrawn successfully');
commit;
END;
/
```

Comment: I believe your error lies in `account.Balance%TYPE(20)`. Binding to a type doesn't accept any parameters, so the `(20)` should be omitted. I would also recommend reviewing [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase your chances of getting a quick and helpful answer. In this case, additional details such as the exact errors reported could have been helpful.

Comment: Also, unless some error happens (such as no_data_found or too_many_rows), the final DBMS_OUTPUT will always be executed so you'll sometimes get two messages which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?